# In which language should I code conditional breakpoints in gdb?

Tags: gdb, conditional-breakpoint

I'm very confused about conditional breakpoints in gdb.

Recently, I wanted to put a breakpoint which breaks when a specific variable is equal to "foo" in a C++ program.

To do that I typed this in the gdb CLI :

```
break LINE_NUMBER if strcmp(myVar, "foo") == 0
```

but it took me a very long time and a lot of tries to find how to code it.

I've first started with :

```
break LINE_NUMBER if myVar == "foo"

break LINE_NUMBER if myVar.c_str() == "foo"

...
```

before I finally found out conditional breakpoints **MAY** have to be programmed in C.

Anyone knows where the rules to code conditional breakpoints are written ?

I've read the documentation but didn't find the info I needed...

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Conditions.html#Conditions

Comment: Conditional breakpoints should be written in the language that is current at the time the breakpoint is hit.  I noticed in your first example you used a single `=` symbol, which isn't going to do what you expect, assuming the language is `C`.  That you tried to call `.c_str()` makes me wonder if the language is C++ though.  Maybe you could include an example program and a complete GDB session showing the conditional breakpoints not working as expected, then we can correct things for you.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, I didn't write the == operator properly. I debug C++ code. So what I have to remember is that the language I have to use is simply the one I'm debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation [explicitly states](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Conditions.html#Conditions) that a condition is a Boolean expression in your programming language:

> You can also specify a condition for a breakpoint. A condition is
> just a Boolean expression in your programming language (see
> Expressions).

Your program is written in C++ so in theory any valid C++ Boolean expression should work. But in practice GDB has a limited support of C++ expressions, only some subset of them works, `strcmp(myVar, "foo") == 0` is one of the examples which works. You can find some areas of improvement on [Expression Evaluation on GDB Wiki](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/Expressions).